# Should the render system know the entity manager?

Tags: architecture

In an entity-component based game architecture, I think the entity manager is a "high-level" system, and the render system a "low-level" system.

When I edit the position component of the entity, should the render system be aware of the entity manager, and get the position over it, or should there be no low-level system communicate with a high-level system?

I think that this should not be the case. Instead, if an entity is moved, the scene manager (also "high-level") should call a "move" function of the render system, and the render system updates the position. That means that every entity interaction has to be a function in my render system.

I'm afraid that I get cyclic dependencies in the first case. Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical ECS way to handle this is to abstract a level in your systems layering. Your design looks something like this:

```
render <--> transform <--> physics
                |           /
                |          /
               gameplay logic
```

Anything that needs to know where entities are at will pull that information from the transform system. Physics updates or game logic that move the entities will push the results into the transform system.

If you really need to know if an entity moved this frame (you need this less often than you might think) then you can either keep a secondary list of transforms from the last frame to compare against, set a dirty bit on the transform data which is cleared at the end of the frame, or insert the entity's id into a sorted set or bitmap of moved entities that's cleared each frame.

More complex engines will indeed give the renderer its own completely separate idea of scene nodes and transforms that isn't tied into the ECS at all, and some system in the ECS is responsible for synchronization high-level transform updates with the renderer's scene nodes. The diagram above would look almost identical in this case except that the `render` entry would be split between an ECS `render_system` which interfaces with `transform` and a separate `render_scene` module that interfaces with `render_system`.

Comment: That means, this architecture is valid?  
[Image from Architecture](http://i58.tinypic.com/34yz21x.png)

Comment: @Dominik2000: sure, why not?

Comment: I was not quite sure, but now with your explanation it makes sense. I don't really know what a low level system and what a high level system defines, but now I get it!